# Why we call the method for solving ODEs "Variation Of Parameters"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just started reading about [Variation Of Parameters method](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) which is used for solving Ordinary Differential Equations.
I wonder why we call this method "variation of parameters" ? I mean which parameters are varied in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters or coefficients $c_k$ in the linear combination of the basis solutions get changed from constant to "variable" functions $u_k(t)$.